# ffmpeg: mkv to mp4 with subtitles hardcoded

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I don't understand something. I'm trying this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -vf subtitles=input.mkv output.mp4
```

But I have this error:

```
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
```

A solution I found is make it in 3 times, first convert to mp4 :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subttles=input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:2 tmp.mp4
```

Then extract subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:s:1 subs.srt
```

Then hardcode subtitle in mp4 :

```
ffmpeg -i tmp.mp4 -vf subtitles=subs.srt output.mp4
```

I was wondering if someone knows how to do this in 1 command or can explain me why my first command doesn't work.

Comment: Share full log of first command.

Answer (score 0):

no found the answer yet but i can do in 2 command :

first extract subtitles :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:s:1 subs.srt
```

then convert to mp4 with subtitles :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -vf subtitles=subs.srt output.mp4
```

i guess if my first command not work, it's because with mkv as subtitles source, the programm doesn't know wich stream we wan't to use.